# Is there a hardware encoding framework for linux

Tags: linux, video-encoding, hardware-acceleration

Is there a VideoToolBox / Microsoft Media Foundation like API that provides functions calls to perform hardware accelerated video encoding and decoding on Linux?

For my specific purpose, you can assume that using ffmpeg or its libraries is not allowed.

Comment: What do you mean by "hardware encoding"? Is this for designing circuits?

Comment: Hardware accelerated video encoding.

Comment: Beyond the fact that tool recommendation requests are categorically off-topic: If we don't know what basis you're ruling out a solution on, we don't know which other tools should be considered ruled out as well. For example, ffmpeg uses nvidia's libvdpau library
 -- does that mean libvdpau is itself off the table?

Comment: GStreamer is certainly a video processing framework which has encoding as a subset of its functionality, and it has _some_ available accelerated plugins (see https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer-vaapi f/e), but whether it's a "hardware encoding framework" in the sense that you mean... well, it's not clear what sense you mean, so _shrug_.